# How to log to DevTools console from a devtools page?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I have a *devtools.html* file that has a *script.js* which contains:

```
console.log('started...')
```

In *manifest.json*, I have:

```
"devtools_page": "devtools.html"
```

However, when I run my extension and open a DevTools window, I don't see the log. If I `throw` an error in *script.js*, I can see that the error occurred in the `chrome://extensions` page, so I know that this script is loaded. However, that log doesn't appear anywhere. Aren't a devtools page's logs supposed to appear in the DevTools window?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### View `console.log()` messages

- Undock devtools into a separate window (in devtools toolbar, the three-dot menu)
- Focus devtools window
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> or <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> to open **devtools-on-devtools** where you'll see the output

#### Output in the web page console using [chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.eval](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_inspectedWindow#method-eval):

```js
const foo = {bar: 123};
chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.eval(`console.log(${JSON.stringify(foo)})`);
```